# How to get the lower co-ordinate of images in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a image and it is inside a div. I want to know what would be the lower co-ordinates for the image. Like if it a rectangle with corners A,B,C and D with A as the bottom left corner I want to get the co-ordinates of that. Could you let me know how I could achieve that using JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: note that if you don't want jQuery, this is a straight forward plain JS call: `element.getBoundingClientRect()`, which gives you back an object with top/left/width/height/etc information

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.position()`  to get `left` and `top` coordinates(`top left corner`).
to get the `bottom left corner` just add image height to top coordinate.

```js
$(window).load(function(){ //to make sure all images are loaded
  console.log($('img').position().left);
  console.log($('img').position().top + $('img').height());
});
```

```css
div { padding: 30px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
```

Comment: I added the height to the position.top() and it does not show the image.

Comment: @Valla You can check the updated code, the problem is that the code ran before loading the image

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with JQuery `position()` and return `left` and `top`

```js
var pos = $('img').position();
$('.result').append('(x: ' + pos.left + ', y: ' + pos.top + ')');
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
</div>
<span class="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to use `getBoundingClientRect()`

```
var image = $( "img" );
var imageBounds = image.get(0).getBoundingClientRect();

var imageLeft = imageBounds.left;
var imageBottom = imageBounds.bottom;
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chriswatts91/7prx7x7k/)

But you could also use jQuery's `.position()` to get the top and left coordinates then to calculate the bottom and right position just add `.height()` or `.width()`

```
var image = $( "img" );
var imagePosition = image.position();
var imageHeight = image.height();

var imageLeft = imagePosition.left;
var imageBottom = imagePosition.top + imageHeight;
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chriswatts91/oLvf09cv/1/)

or without using jQuery:

```
var image = document.getElementById("image");
var imageBounds = image.getBoundingClientRect();

var imageLeft = imageBounds.left;
var imageBottom = imageBounds.bottom;
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chriswatts91/fuez41jp/3/)

Comment: I am getting 0 as the value of height and width of the image when I try the above code.Could you let me know what might be the reason

Comment: Sound's like it's running before the image has loaded... Are you running once the document's ready? `$( document ).ready(function() {`

Comment: I have added it in document.ready and it works.But the location is not working properly I am getting the value 540 and 860 as image height and width and I add it to top and left it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the demo on codepen: http://codepen.io/ssh33/pen/AXdVER**

Waits for the image to download to get the width and height and calls `GetCoordinates()`.

If the image has been previously cached `$("#image").load()` will never fire. In this case `$(window).load()` will call `GetCoordinates()` instead. `GetCoordinates()` checks for non-numeric width/height and retrieves it if necessary.

Recalculates on window resize.

```
var img_width, img_height, x, y;

$("#image").load(function() {
      img_width = this.width;   
      img_height = this.height;
});

var GetCoordinates = function(){
      if (isNaN(img_width) || isNaN(img_height)){
              img_width = $("#image").width();   
              img_height = $("#image").height();
      }

      var img_left = $("#image").offset().left;
      x = img_width + img_left;

      var img_top = $("#image").offset().top;
      y = img_height + img_top;
}  

$(window).load(function() {
      GetCoordinates(); 
});

$(window).resize(function() {
      GetCoordinates(); 
});
```